# COUNTIF with TRANSPOSE function

Tags: excel, transpose, countif

I need help in building a COUNTIF formula that can be dragged vertically but counts horizontally. I tried using the TRANSPOSE function but it doesn't work.

This is how my excel sheets are structured:

- In sheet 1, vertically from B3 to B77 there is a list of KPIs, in the same sheet horizontally from from I3 to AY3 there's a particular Group ID. The table produced, is filled with "X" where a KPI was achieved by the group.
- In sheet 2, result sheet, I have the same Group ID but it is now displayed vertically. What I would like to do is to COUNT the number of X for each Group ID (which is going to be an horizontal count in sheet 1), while being able to drag the formula in sheet 2 vertically. I hope this is more clear now. Thanks

Thank you for put help!

Comment: This needs further description. Especially how your data is in the sheet and what needs to be counted. If I have data in `A1:Gn` and a formula `=COUNTIF($A1:$G1,"a")` in `I1`, then I can drag this formula vertically downwards and it counts horizontally how often "a" occurs in the current row in columns `A:G`.

Comment: You are right: 

- In sheet 1, vertically from B3 to B77 there is a list of KPIs, in the same sheet horizontally from from I3 to AY3 there's a particular Group ID. The table produced, is filled with "X" where a KPI was achieved by the group. 

- In sheet 2, result sheet, I have the same Group ID but it is now displayed horizontally. 

What I would like to do is to COUNT the number of X for each Group ID (which is going to be an horizontal count in sheet 1), while being able to drag the formula in sheet 2 vertically.

I hope this is more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide additional information there and not in comments. Comments are not thought for this and are not good readable because of not much formattable.

Comment: Btw.: "In sheet 1, .... horizontally from from I3 to AY3 there's a particular Group ID" ... "In sheet 2, result sheet, I have the same Group ID but it is now displayed horizontally." ??? So Group ID is horizontally in both sheets? Not really clear until now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's have an example accordíng to your description:

Sheet1:

[image]

Not clear why "KPI 01" is in the same row 3 as the Group-ID headings but nevertheless....

Sheet2:

[image]

Formula in `B3` is

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!$I$3:$AY$10000,,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$I$3:$AY$3,0)),"x")
```

so if you drag this formula downwards, the `$A3` changes to `$A4`, `$A5`, ... and so `Match` will always look for the Group ID of the current row.